# How do I scrape this tag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler

```
  <div id="hide-editing-34536258">1/2 and 2/1 are reciprocals.</div>
```

This is the tag I wanna scrape and I wanna print `1/2 and 2/1 are reciprocals.`

I'll print it through `get_text()` but I don't know how I scrape the tag.

I can do this.

```
find_all({"class":"hide-editing-3453658"}
```

but there are more tags to scrape and they have different numbers after 'high-editing-'

and I can't find any rules in the numbers.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute is `id` not `class` and you have give the tag you are looking in the `find_all` method. You can use `regex` to find all elements with certain pattern.

```
In [61]: import re
In [62]: a = """  <div id="hide-editing-34536258">1/2 and 2/1 are reciprocals.</div>
    ...:    <div id="hide-editing-345258">1/4 and 2/1 are reciprocals.</div>
    ...:   <div id="hide-editing-346258">1/5 and 2/1 are reciprocals.</div>
    ...: """

In [63]: soup = BeautifulSoup(a, "html.parser")

In [64]: all_divs = dates = soup.findAll("div", {"id" : re.compile('hide-editing.*')})

In [65]: all_divs
Out[65]:
[<div id="hide-editing-34536258">1/2 and 2/1 are reciprocals.</div>,
 <div id="hide-editing-345258">1/4 and 2/1 are reciprocals.</div>,
 <div id="hide-editing-346258">1/5 and 2/1 are reciprocals.</div>]

In [66]: [i.text.strip() for i in all_divs]
Out[66]:
['1/2 and 2/1 are reciprocals.',
 '1/4 and 2/1 are reciprocals.',
 '1/5 and 2/1 are reciprocals.']
```

Comment: thank you. I tried your code but it says 'name 're' is not defined' what should I do?

Comment: my version is 3.8

Comment: I solved thanks to you! How do I figure out what function I need when I 'm stuck?

Comment: It depends on the attributes of the html tags. You can use `find`, `findAll`, `find_all`

Comment: is there any way I can exclude some tags with certain patterns? when I use find_all

Comment: <div id="hide-editing-33796166"><span class="mention_name"><a rel="nofollow" href="https://hinative.com/en-US/profiles/3203434">@nesmabythesea</a></span> thank youz!</div>

Comment: you can give only tags which you are looking for in `find_all`

Comment: I don't want tags with span class='mention_name" I can post another question and you can answer there if that's more convenient for you

Comment: If not me, others who have better knowledge can answer. You can post another question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with regular expression?

```
import re

text = '<div id="hide-editing-34536258">1/2 and 2/1 are reciprocals.</div>'
parsedText=re.findall('>([^<]+)', text)

print(parsedText[0])
```